# Oracle Regexp_substr String

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I have String like `a123bcd-e2343fg-hij-dfgh`
and I want OUTPUT `e2343fg-hij-dfgh` using Regular_expression in oracle.

```
select regexp_substr('abcd-efg-hij','-[^-]+'1) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may apply `regexp_substr` with `[^-]+[-^]` pattern and then `ltrim` as :

```
select ltrim('a123bcd-e2343fg-hij-dfgh',
         regexp_substr('a123bcd-e2343fg-hij-dfgh','[^-]+[-^]')) as output_string        
  from dual;
```

or better to call with bind variable :

```
select ltrim('&str', regexp_substr('&str','[^-]+[-^]')) as output_string
  from dual;
```

where `&str` may be replaced with `a123bcd-e2343fg-hij-dfgh` after prompted.

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/ACSTG72287)

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr('abcd-efg-hij',
               regexp_instr('abcd-efg-hij','-[^-]+')+1,length('abcd-efg-hij')) 
  from dual;
```

try this

Comment: Please explain your code and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why *regular expression*, when a trivial `SUBSTR + INSTR` does the job nicely & quickly? True, it will look *smarter*, but I can't see any other benefit.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'a123bcd-e2343fg-hij-dfgh' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
----------------
e2343fg-hij-dfgh

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, `regexp_replace` works too.  This regex matches anything up to and including the first dash, and remembers the rest which it returns.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'a123bcd-e2343fg-hij-dfgh' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(str, '^.*?-(.*)', '\1')
from tbl;
```

Keep in mind if regexp_substr() does not find a match, it returns NULL but if regexp_replace() does not find a match it return the original string.